# NSString.appendingPathComponent(_:) not working correctly on Linux

Tags: swift, linux, nsstring

Apple's documentation of the [NSString.appendingPathComponent(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1417069-appendingpathcomponent) describes:
[image]

The method works as expected on macOS but fails on linux. Is there any workaround? Is this a feature or bug? Where can we report this?

[Run online](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/597d02d0f5cb4d144241f576)

```
import Foundation


extension String {
    func appendingPathComponent(_ str: String) -> String {
        return NSString(string: self).appendingPathComponent(str)
    }
}

// prints correctly: "/tmp/scratch.tiff"
print("/tmp".appendingPathComponent("scratch.tiff"))

// should print: "/tmp/scratch.tiff" but prints "/tmp//scratch.tiff"
print("/tmp/".appendingPathComponent("scratch.tiff"))

// prints correctly: "/scratch.tiff"
print("/".appendingPathComponent("scratch.tiff"))

// should print: "scratch.tiff" but prints "/scratch.tiff"
print("".appendingPathComponent("scratch.tiff"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely a bug, since it runs counter to the documentation. One of them needs to be fixed and I think it's the code. Open a new bug [here](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5580?jql=).

With Swift, Apple removed all these path APIs from `String`, which has been a poor fit in my opinion. Apple's preferred method to do path manipulation is with `URL`:

```
print(URL(fileURLWithPath: "/tmp").appendingPathComponent("scratch.tiff").path)
print(URL(fileURLWithPath: "/tmp/").appendingPathComponent("scratch.tiff").path)
print(URL(fileURLWithPath: "/").appendingPathComponent("scratch.tiff").path)
print(URL(fileURLWithPath: "").appendingPathComponent("scratch.tiff").path)
```

The last line behaves differently from `NSString`. It appends `scratch.tiff` to the *current directory*. In other word, it's expanded form of `./scratch.tiff`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've just filed a [bug report](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5582).